# VSCode Python interactive window freezes when using %matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I have latest version of VSCode and the standard Python extension installed.

I often develop interactively (Shift-Enter) with an interactive Jupyter Window, often including matplotlib and I want the windows externally so I can zoom and resize.

It has worked fine in the past but now I have problems (same problem Mac and Linux).
If I

1. start a Jupyter interactive window
2. Write %matplotlib (I am using the Qt5Agg backend)
3. Then, with almost any simple command the interactive window freezes (see attached snapshot).

This works fine with the same set of packages and backends in, e.g., PyCharm. I have attached a snapshot that illustrates my problem [image illustrating problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tttgu.png)

I hope you have some advice or fix for me, since VSCode is currently not useable for me.

regards,
Erik

Comment: Unfortunately no. I don't have the freetype package installed and I run cpython from python.org in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it looks like an issue of jupyter notebook, after the version of `v2021.10.1001409655` this problem can be found, but if you downgrade to the early version, you will lose the Intellisense.

So, it's suggested to avoid executing `%matplotlib` in the jupyter notebook for now.

I have submitted [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8322) on Github.